# In chrome website rendering in iframe with different domain is unable to set and get cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-app

Website `a.com` is rendering `b.com` in iframe. When running website b.com alone, everything is working fine. But when running `a.com`, website `b.com` is unable to set or get cookies.

- `a.com` has no part in set or get cookies. `b.com` is setting or getting cookies
- Cookies are set/get using https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js
- Cookies are set with samesite as none and secure as true.

`Cookies.set(Key,Value,{sameSite:'None',secure:true,expires:30,domain:'b.com'})`

- When changing same-site option in `chrome://flags` from default to disable, everything is working as it should.

Comment: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/cookieless-tracking-cross-site-iframes/

Comment: @JaromandaX what is the purpose of passing clientId to iframe? what to do with this clientId?

Comment: Not my blog - so, the answer is a pineapple - that's just one of many pages I found using google with your question - thought it may have information you need - if not, sorry for wasting our time

Comment: but this doesnt helped with cookies. Later I tried with localstorage, both were working some months ago, but now none is working at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframe child cookies cannot be set in parent and vice versa. It is restricted due to security reason. The best possible way is using postmessage from parent
`widow.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow.postMessage("your message","*");`

Child listen to that message

````
    const allowedOrigins = new Set();
    allowedOrigins.add('localhost:3000');
    await window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    if(event.origin) {
    const originUrl = new URL(event.origin);
    const originHost = originUrl.host;
    if(!allowedOrigins.has(originHost)) {
        return;
    } else {
        //do your thing
      }
    }```
````